# Unable to download file from firebase through android studio

Tags: firebase, storage, android-studio-2.2

i just want to download an image from Firebase storage,but i am having these issues.My google play service is up to date.I have an image "dog.jpg" in bucket and no other file.
[Firebase bucket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJHTg.jpg)

My mainActivity code

```js
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private StorageReference pathRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("dog.jpg");
    private ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.imageView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    }

    public void getImage(View v){
        File localFile;
        try {
            localFile = File.createTempFile("images","jpg");
            pathRef.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    //Local temp file has been created
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    //handle error
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage()+"\n"+e.getCause(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }catch (IOException exception){
            Toast.makeText(this, "IOEXCEPTION", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Errors i am getting.

```html
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 11020000 but found 9683470
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.firebasestorage not found.
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.firebasestorage:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.firebasestorage:0
E/NetworkRqFactoryProxy: NetworkRequestFactoryProxy failed with a RemoteException:
                         com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$zzc: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
                             at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.zza(Unknown Source)
                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.ace.<init>(Unknown Source)
                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.ace.zzg(Unknown Source)
                             at com.google.firebase.storage.FileDownloadTask.run(Unknown Source)
                             at com.google.firebase.storage.zzr.run(Unknown Source)
                             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
E/FileDownloadTask: Unable to create firebase storage network request.
                    android.os.RemoteException
                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ace.<init>(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ace.zzg(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.FileDownloadTask.run(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.zzr.run(Unknown Source)
                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
                    An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
                     Code: -13000 HttpResult: 0
E/StorageException: null
                    android.os.RemoteException
                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ace.<init>(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ace.zzg(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.FileDownloadTask.run(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.zzr.run(Unknown Source)
                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
                    An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
                     Code: -13000 HttpResult: 0
E/StorageException: null
                    android.os.RemoteException
                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ace.<init>(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ace.zzg(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.FileDownloadTask.run(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.zzr.run(Unknown Source)
                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

whats wrong with my code...i even tried it on real device but still unable to download this file my storage rules are:
`service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write:if true
    }
  }
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Play services is not up to date as you suggest.  This error message tells you what's going on:

```
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 11020000 but found 9683470
```

The message suggests that you're using client library version 11.0.2, but Play services 9.6.83 is installed on the device.  The version of Play has to be greater than or equal to the version of the client library in order for things to work.